# How To Create Permission and Assign Middleware To Route Dynamically Using Spatie Permission Package in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have some Voucher Types:

- Payment
- Receipt
- Contra
  -Journal
- Etc.

User can Create multiple Voucher under Voucher Type.

Payment

- Payment 1
- Payment 2
- Payment 3
- Etc.

Receipt

- Receipt 1
- Receipt 2
- Receipt 3
- Etc.

Contra

- Contra 1
- Contra 2
- Contra 3
- Etc.

Journal

- Journal 1
- Journal 2
- Journal 3
- Etc.

In Laravel, I am using Spatie Permission package, Using this package i can create multiple permission dynamically, and also assign them to role but how can I validate every voucher permission to route using middleware?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::middleware([ 'auth' ])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('SuperAdmin')) {
                return redirect()->route('superadmin.dashboard');
            } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            } elseif (Auth::user()->hasRole('Vendor')) {
                return redirect()->route('vendor.dashboard');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A role can be assigned to any user: `$user->assignRole('writer');`
A role can be removed from a user: `$user->removeRole('writer');`

A permission can be given to a role: `$role->givePermissionTo('edit articles');`
You can determine if a role has a certain permission: `$role->hasPermissionTo('edit articles');`
A permission can be revoked from a role: `$role->revokePermissionTo('edit articles');`

Assigning Direct Permissions To A User: `$user->assignRole('writer');`
`$user->givePermissionTo('delete articles');`

Comment: In my application I have fixed only Super Admin. Super Admin can create multiple role dynamically. Also have some fixed permissions and i can validate it using can() operator but in voucher section Super Admin can create multiple Vouchers and assign them to users to access. So how can i validate dynamically created vouchers using can() operator? Is there have any other way to validate it?

Comment: your concept is the same as spatie package. but spatie manage role and model permission for users. in your case you have to create new table 'user_voucher' that contain two columns one is user_id and second is voucher_id. and you have to define relation between this two 'users' and 'voucher' tables.

in your user model make relation
-> public function voucher() 
     {
           return $this->belongsToMany(Voucher::class, 'user_voucher', 'user_id', 'voucher_id');
     }

Comment: Can i have handle this situation using spatie package? Because when Super Admin create Voucher i have added a new Permission to permission_table

$role = Role::where('name', 'Super Admin');
$permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'payment1']);
$role->givePermissionTo($permission);

Using this way i can create multiple vouchers dynamically. eg. payment2, payment3, etc

But how can i assign middlware in route?

Route::get('/{vou_id}/index', [AccVoucherController::class, 'index'])->middleware('can:???')->name('payment.index');